# Add to Codeigniter Form Validation a callback to check if user is logged in

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

So when a form is submitted I want to check if the user is logged in, so I set a CI callback like this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('comment', 'Comment', 'callback__check_login|required|min_length[8]');

public function _check_login($str)
    {
        if (!$this->data['user']->logged_in)
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('_check_login', 'You need to be logged in to post.');
            return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
```

I understand that CI '`reads`' from left to right, so first it must check for '`callback__check_login`' then '`required`' and then '`min_length[8]`', but it doesnt.

First it checks for '`required`', then for '`callback__check_login`' and then '`min_length[8]`'...

WTF?

Comment: What does the documentation say? I mean isn't it just that way?

Answer (score 0):

http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/190190/

Required validation is the higher priority than others.
I think it is best way if you check the session that user logged in or not. Just put if else condition, it will helps you or you can write a new callback function for checking required field. and call it after _check_login function.

Comment: Ok yes, that is what I want, how can I create a callback function for checking required fields?